Looking for test monitoring tool
I am looking for a test monitoring tool that can collect the results of various tests. It should have options to filter and search the test results. As a bonus it should have options to comment single tests or test runs.
Test could be Ranorex tests, Visual Studio unit tests, COM/API tests etc.
We already had a look at some commercial products like TestRail but most of these are way too expensive for our needs.

If I understood you correctly, you are looking for Test Management System (TMS).
There is open source TestLink. It leaves much to be desired in terms of interface and usability. We tried to get used to it a couple of years ago, but it didn't work out. At that time, it seemed to be completely abandoned, but now, judging by the commits, it continues to develop. Although not vigorously. But perhaps now or in the future, the situation will change for the better.
Now we use Test IT, it is quite pleasant to use. But the practice of writing checklists and test cases has not really taken root with us. Therefore, I cannot say that we use it often and actively. But I would recommend considering it as an option.
